# Cannot send request paramters through hyperlink in report

Tags: java, hyperlink, jasper-reports

It's been two days now and i am stuck at a very small problem and i now i have given up so i am posting my question here.

I am working locally and i have created a hyperlink text in my report. I'm using reference type link and in reference tab I have put
"/cibs/printInvoice.doo?prepaidAll_action=prepaidAll&invoiceId=786654" (i have given invoiceId in queryString as well) like this:

[image]

and I have given invoiceId = 786654 even in link parameter tab.
But when page is loaded and I see the link. It skips the "&invoiceId=786654" part like this:

[image]

This i think is because i am using struts maybe (not sure). But at least I should receive the *invoiceId* i gave in link parameter.

In my code I am getting the parameter like this in my Java code:

```
Map parameters = new HashMap();
parameters.put("invoiceId", request.getParameter("invoiceId"));
```

but i receive null. Can someone please tell me how do i send *invoiceId* as a request parameter.

Comment: Does your code work well if you just calling a right url (with *invoiceId*)?

Comment: Have you tried changing `&` to `&amp;`?

Comment: @AlexK yes works fine and ,
tobi meaning??

Comment: Try putting `"/cibs/printInvoice.doo?prepaidAll_action=prepaidAll&amp;invoiceId=786654"` into the hyperlink.

Comment: nope still doesn't show it

Comment: Try changing the type temporarily to `Report execution` and add the parameter there. Then change it back to `Reference` and check the source code if there are parameters added. Now try the report.

Comment: i have tried reportexecution before , it doesn't become a link

Comment: nope didn't work :/

Comment: `Report execution` shouldn't be selected but it should be switched back to `Reference`.